# How to by bypass Tomcat form-based authentication when redirecting from Google OAuth API

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, oauth

I hope someone here can help me with the following problem:

I have created a sample Java web application with Tomcat7, a simple tomcat form based authentication with JDBC Realm with MYSQL Database Driver.

When i encrypted the user password using the Digest MD5, the system works perfectly. But when i use the Login with Google Auth API, and after redirecting from Google sign-in, my system should bypass / skip the login form based and create the session if the user has defined in my local database and successful login in google.

So, using the Digest algorithm in tomcat realm (MD5, MD2, SHA), i cannot decrypt the password in db after the redirecting from Google and force login to my web app. For this reason, i need to enforce and create session after the response from Google OAuth.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hashing is not Encryption ("decrypt")

Comment: you are right. do u have a solution to fix the above problem?